# How to use auth 2.0 using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, webview, oauth-2.0

I am developing an application which is using OAuth2.0:
what I am doing is through my app user login via webview and I am getting code using this method:

```
// MARK: - WEbview  field delegate
      func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {

        print("URL to load--\(request.URLString)")
        if(request.URLString.containsString("code="))
        {
            let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: request.URLString)
            let queryItems = urlComponents?.queryItems
            let param1 = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first
            print(param1?.value)
            strCode = param1!.value
            self.callAPI(self)
            return false


        }
        return true
    }
```

This is the code I need to pass in accesstokenAPI

```
`func callAPI(sender : AnyObject {
        let delegate1 = AppDelegate.sharedObj()
        print(strCode)
        print(delegate1.CLIENT_ID)
        print(delegate1.CLIENT_SECRET)
        let URLpath :String = "https://office.example.com/oauth/access_token"
        let  params : [String :  AnyObject] = ["client_id" :delegate1.CLIENT_ID! , "client_secret" :delegate1.CLIENT_SECRET! , "code" :strCode! , "redirect_uri" : "google.com"]
        print(params)
    apiObj.dataWithPost(URLpath, cTag: 0, paramter: params)
    GlobelHelper.showLoadingView(self.view!)
    }`
```

All this code is according to doc provided by that company
but I am getting  this error  in response.

`["error": invalid_client, "error_description": Client credentials were not found in the headers or body]`
Actually, I don't know is this write way or not : It is working in POSTMAN.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Check this one out: https://grokswift.com/alamofire-OAuth2/

Comment: will it work for any type of authentication'

Comment: I think i have almost done only some small thing i am missing